# hidesBackButton doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
[BGFacebookDelegateSingleton.singleton logoutFacebook];
BGLogin * login = [[BGLogin alloc]init];
UINavigationController * nav= self.navigationController;
[nav pushViewController:login animated:YES];
login.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;//Button doesn't go out
PO(@(login.navigationItem.hidesBackButton)); //Confirm it's YES
while (false);
```

I wonder what could possibly be wrong with this. It works on other places but not after

```
[BGFacebookDelegateSingleton.singleton logoutFacebook];
```

The content of
    [BGFacebookDelegateSingleton.singleton logoutFacebook];

is only:
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try writing `[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];` in login's `viewDidLoad()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works. I still need an explanation why it didn't work in the first place. However, if no other answers, please remind me to select this as the right answer.

Comment: Umm i am not sure though.. but here is what I think... Even if you push the view controller unless and until it is not visible on the screen.. we cannot access some of the parameters or even if we assign something it does not takes effect (Even I dont know exactly why). And hence I prefer viewDidLoad for this kind of the tasks.

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I should access the view first, make sure it's loaded before assigning stuffs.